# Invoke a JsonGenerator method for each element in a set

Tags: java

I have a method that can write a product object into a file using JsonGenerator.
(productToJSON)

I want to use a second method to write all products from a HashSet into the JSON file using the JsonGenerator stream. I believe there is a problem with opening and closing the stream (the file contains only the last product). So I could open and close the stream in my second method but then the first would not work for 1 product any more.

Please let me know:

1. Is it possible to do what I want using 2 methods?
2. Is there a better way to do it?

```
public void productToJSON(Product product, String fileName) throws Exception {
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    JsonGenerator jsonGen = jsonFactory.createJsonGenerator(file, JsonEncoding.UTF8);
    jsonGen.setPrettyPrinter(new DefaultPrettyPrinter());

    jsonGen.writeStartObject();
    jsonGen.writeStringField("name", product.getName());
    jsonGen.writeNumberField("weight", product.getWeight());
    jsonGen.writeNumberField("stock", product.getStock());
    jsonGen.writeNumberField("price", product.getPrice());
    jsonGen.writeNumberField("rating", product.getRating());
    jsonGen.writeEndObject();
    jsonGen.close();
}

public void productsToJSON(String fileName) throws Exception {
    for (Product p : this.products) {
        this.productToJSON(p, fileName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach one - always call productsToJSON:

```
private void productToJSON(Product product, JsonGenerator jsonGen) throws Exception {
    jsonGen.writeStartObject();
    jsonGen.writeStringField("name", product.getName());
    jsonGen.writeNumberField("weight", product.getWeight());
    jsonGen.writeNumberField("stock", product.getStock());
    jsonGen.writeNumberField("price", product.getPrice());
    jsonGen.writeNumberField("rating", product.getRating());
    jsonGen.writeEndObject();
}

public void productsToJSON(String fileName) throws Exception {
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    JsonGenerator jsonGen = jsonFactory.createJsonGenerator(file, JsonEncoding.UTF8);
    jsonGen.setPrettyPrinter(new DefaultPrettyPrinter());
    if (this.products.size > 1) {
        jsonGen.writeStartArray(this.products.size)
    }
    for (Product p: this.products) {
        this.productToJSON(p, jsonGen);
    }
    if (this.products.size > 1) {
        jsonGen.writeEndArray()
    }
    jsonGen.close();
}
```

Approach two - one private and two public methods:

```
private void productToJSON(Product product, JsonGenerator jsonGen) throws Exception {
    jsonGen.writeStartObject();
    jsonGen.writeStringField("name", product.getName());
    jsonGen.writeNumberField("weight", product.getWeight());
    jsonGen.writeNumberField("stock", product.getStock());
    jsonGen.writeNumberField("price", product.getPrice());
    jsonGen.writeNumberField("rating", product.getRating());
    jsonGen.writeEndObject();
}

public void productsToJSON(String fileName) throws Exception {
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    JsonGenerator jsonGen = jsonFactory.createJsonGenerator(file, JsonEncoding.UTF8);
    jsonGen.setPrettyPrinter(new DefaultPrettyPrinter());
    jsonGen.writeStartArray(this.products.size)
    for (Product p: this.products) {
        this.productToJSON(p, jsonGen);
    }
    jsonGen.writeEndArray()
    jsonGen.close();
}

public void productToJSON(Product p, String fileName) throws Exception {
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    JsonGenerator jsonGen = jsonFactory.createJsonGenerator(file, JsonEncoding.UTF8);
    jsonGen.setPrettyPrinter(new DefaultPrettyPrinter());
    this.productToJSON(p, jsonGen);
    jsonGen.close();
}
```

Comment: remove `jsonGen.close();` in `productToJSON`.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate that your answer provided a solution without changing my code too much as this helps me understand it easily. I learned a new thing from your answer(the trick with private and public methods) and got some hint regarding where to look for (writeStartArray) to deeper understand how this stream actually works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ObjectMapper to create a json from Java Object. [And Setter-Getter method in the POJO]. Use DefaultPrettyPrinter to create ObjectWriter.

Note:
No need to set properties in the JsonGenerator.
like,

```
jsonGen.writeStringField("name", product.getName());
```

Refer below example.

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultPrettyPrinter;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;

    public class Demo {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            List<Product> list = new ArrayList<Product>();
            list.add(new Product("Sample Product", 123012));
            list.add(new Product("Sample 1 Product 1", 2134));
            list.add(new Product("Sample 1 Product 2", 4353));
            list.add(new Product("Sample 1 Product 3", 34345));
            productsToJSON(list, "Test.txt");
        }

        private static void productsToJSON(List<Product> products, String fileName) throws Exception {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(new DefaultPrettyPrinter());
            writer.writeValue(new File(fileName), products);
        }
    }

    class Product {
        private String name;
        private Integer weight;

        public Product(String name, Integer weight) {
            this.name = name;
            this.weight = weight;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Integer getWeight() {
            return weight;
        }

        public void setWeight(Integer weight) {
            this.weight = weight;
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
    [ {
      "name" : "Sample Product",
      "weight" : 123012
    }, {
      "name" : "Sample1 Product1",
      "weight" : 123012
    } ]
```

Comment: Thank you, however I have no knowledge of "Serializable" and this is not useful for me even though it might be a good answer. Also I want to use streams to do it. But thank you!